# Is "Да, доброе утро." normal Russian?

Tags: phrase, приветствия

On Duolingo, I just encountered the phrase "Да, доброе утро.", which it translated as "Yes, good morning.". Is that considered normal Russian, as if someone were seriously evaluating whether the morning was good or not?

I checked the [discussion forum](https://www.duolingo.com/skill/ru/Phrases-1/3), and while someone asking about this got a lot of upvotes, they haven't received an answer.

I've also [encountered](https://www.duolingo.com/skill/ru/Phrases-1/4) "Да, до свидания!", which it translates as "Yes, goodbye!" which likewise doesn't make sense.

Comment: Do you mean that somebody ask "It is a good morning, isn't it" ?

Comment: It's normal Russian in that sense that it's grammatical, it's not a usual phrase and can be used in quite narrow context - which @Abakan perfectly described.

Comment: There is a narrow use case for a "Да. Доброе утро!" (note that punctuation is slightly different).  "Да" is used as a synonym to "Алло" (Hello) in phone conversations.  So "Да. Доброе утро!" can be said by a receptionist picking up the phone.

Answer (score 6):

It makes no sense as a standalone sentence. One can definitely think of a situation in which these two sentences might sound normal or at least not unnatural.
For example:

> *(after a conversation)*
>
> - Ну, до свидания. (well, goodbye!)
> - Да, до свидания. (yes, goodbye!)

Or:

> - Does "доброе утро" mean "good morning"?
> - Yes, good morning.

Comment: Would it make sense to say "Да, доброе утро" in response to someone saying "доброе утро"?

Comment: No, we  usualy use short answer "Доброе"

Comment: It has got a slightly different meaning with "да". It  reminds of the original sense : The morning is fine.– Yes, it's fine indeed. It's like wordplay, small talk. Not a usual greeting.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Yes, it would make sense. Such words (in general) are extremely often used not because they mean something, but because they just come by one's mind, along the way of private thoughts. Like that guy was thinking of something else, for example, and he remembered to greet you. Or he decided it would make sense to greet you, so he kind of agreed with you: okay, let's greet each other. Not really a common situation, this one.

Answer (score 5):

An example where "да" answers a question, not related directly to "доброе утро". The first speaker is not sure the usual greeting will be appropriate (imagine a phone call to a friend known to work hard on Friday evening). The answer sounds perfectly natural here:

> — Ну как, ты уже выспался (проснулся, отоспался)?
>
> — **Да, доброе утро.**
>
> — Доброе утро.

Similarly (to a departing guest waiting for a cab outside):

> — Ну как, подъехало твоё [только что заказанное] такси?
>
> — **Да, до свидания**.

Answer (score 4):

> Is that considered normal Russian, as if someone were seriously evaluating whether the morning was good or not?

No, of course not. But "да" in Russian doesn't always mean plain "yes". Here it probably stands for something like "Oh, I almost forgot...". Such usage is quite normal in colloquial speech and is also directly mentioned in dictionaries.